# Cannot build 32-bit assembly after installing 32-bit support

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, ld, gnu-assembler

I am trying to build an x86 executable on an x86_64 platform from assembly. I know that I need to install x86 support, so I've installed the libraries:

```
glibc-devel.i386
libstdc++-devel.i386
```

This allows me to successfully build and execute C programs in 32-bit mode via GCC:

```
gcc test.c -o test -m32
./test
Hello world!
```

However, I'm not able to assemble an x86 program from assembly:

```
$gcc -m32 template.s -o test 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Or alternately:

```
$as --32 template.s -o temp
$ld -melf_i386 temp -lc
ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libc.so when searching for -lc
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000080481b0
$./a.out 
-bash: ./a.out: /usr/lib/libc.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I was able to get this running before, but it's been a long time and was on a different computer. The program template.s is below:

```
procedure:
        movl    4(%esp), %eax
        ret

main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp

        pushl   a
        call    procedure

        pushl   %eax
        pushl   $string
        call    printf

        leave
        ret

.section        .rodata
    string:
        .string "result is %d\n"

.section .data
    a:
        .long   -25
```

Comment: Add `.global main` to the top of `template.s` then assemble and link with `gcc -m32 template.s -o test`

Comment: @MichaelPetch And move the `-o test` before the `template.s` operand.

Comment: @FUZxxl : As far as I know the output file can appear anywhere - before or after the the list of objects. I don't believe  GCC or GAS impose an ordering rule outside the object files. Placing the output file at the end the `-o` would be stylistic.

Comment: @MichaelPetch gcc doesn't but POSIX specifies that you should do so. gcc changed their command line parser before (when they started to enforce the order of `-l` operands) and you should not assume that they won't do so in the future.